# Is encrypting a private key inside a pkcs12 file using openssl secure?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl

[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203384) states that encrypting a private key using `openssl rsa -aes256` isn't secure, because the md5 hash of the password is used as encryption key.

But what if I do `openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -name client -out client.p12 -password pass:12345` instead? (Using a better password of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some.**

`openssl pkcs12 -export` through 1.1.x by default encrypts the privatekey (in a PKCS8 'bag') using the scheme `pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC` defined in [PKCS12 aka RFC7292 appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#appendix-C) which uses 3-key TDEA aka 3DES (as it says) and the PBKDF defined in appendix B with SHA-1, 2048 iterations and 8-byte salt; this doesn't appear to have an official name so I just call it PKCS12PBKDF. This seems to be an unwritten convention; all other programs I know of that create PKCS12 also use this scheme, at least by default and sometimes unconditionally. (Update: after 2020 this started to change; some other things now use PBES2 almost always with AES.) In OpenSSL you can use `-keypbe` to specify any PKCS12 scheme (or any PKCS5v1 aka PBES1 scheme, but don't because they're all obsolete and broken) *or* the PKCS5v2 PBES2 scheme with any supported cipher (in CBC mode) but always with PBKDF2, (corrected) SHA-1 through 1.0.x or SHA-256 in 1.1.x up, 2048 iterations, and salt. Although PBKDF2 is technically different from PKCS12PBKDF, the differences don't matter to security AFAICS.
Update: 3.0.0 (released in 2021) up defaults to PBES2 with SHA-256 and AES-256, although you can specify `-legacy [-descert]` to go back to the long-conventional PKCS12 schemes (SHA1 and 3DES for key, either that or SHA1 and RC2-40 for cert).

This fixes the most glaring flaw in OpenSSL's 'legacy' PEM-file encryption, that it uses only one iteration of MD5. (Using MD5 is not a problem in itself; although MD5 is badly broken for collision, that doesn't apply to a PBKDF. But since the letters MD5 now provoke irrational panic in checklisters, managers, and other fairy-dust believers, and we have better hashes available, we use them.) But 2048 iterations is not great; it was considered adequate when PKCS5v2 was published back in 2000 but hardware has improved a lot since then and nowadays 10s or 100s of thousands are usually preferred, and some go for millions or more. More importantly, hardware has *changed* to make raw computation more available in the form of GPUs, FPGAs, and even ASICs, so nowadays an iterated hash is no longer best practice; instead we want a 'memory-hard' function like scrypt or Argon2; see e.g.:
[In 2018, what is the recommended hash to store passwords: bcrypt, scrypt, Argon2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193351/in-2018-what-is-the-recommended-hash-to-store-passwords-bcrypt-scrypt-argon2)
[Are there more modern password hashing methods than bcrypt and scrypt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/are-there-more-modern-password-hashing-methods-than-bcrypt-and-scrypt)
[Is bcrypt better than scrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26245/is-bcrypt-better-than-scrypt)
[Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage)
[How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)
[Why are salted hashes more secure for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure)
[How are SCrypt's memory-hard requirements substituted with more CPU?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73292/how-are-scrypts-memory-hard-requirements-substituted-with-more-cpu)
[Has scrypt been broken, finally?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65660/has-scrypt-been-broken-finally)
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/959/strength-of-multiple-hash-iterations
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12795/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-original-salt-to-each-hash-iteration-of-a-password
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/is-bcrypt-better-than-gnuppgs-iteratedsalted-hashing-method
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897434/password-security-sha1-sha256-or-sha512

If you want the most secure private key encryption in OpenSSL 1.1.0 up (these versions are now widespread though not everywhere) use `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -scrypt` plus optionally `-scrypt_[Nrp] $val` if you want to customize although the defaults should be satisfactory. Note however this is not necessarily portable to anything other than OpenSSL. You can also use PKCS8 with PBES2/PBKDF2 but increase the iterations with `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -iter $num` (1.1.x up defaults to PBES2/SHA-256/AES-256 but for 1.0.x or lower specify `-v2 aes-256-cbc` or similar); this is much more interoperable and probably secure enough (given a good password). (As I noted on a different answer to the Q you link.) Update: as @muxmuse comments, for 3.0.0 up `pkcs12 -export` also supports `-iter N` -- and as noted above also defaults to PBES2/SHA-256/AES-256.

Comment: Very good answer! `pkcs8 -scrypt` is exactly what I need. But, are you saying that PBKDF2 (with SHA1 and 2048 iterations) isn't more secure than PKCS12PBKDF? What if you do `openssl pkcs12 -keypbe AES-256-CBC -certpbe AES-256-CBC -macalg sha512`? Still worse than `pkcs8 -scrypt` I suppose due to the low number of iterations?

Comment: Yes, I see no security difference between PKCS12PBKDF and (PKCS5) PBKDF2 for the same hash&iterations. All `pkcs12` options are iterated hash and thus not as preferred as scrypt because BOTH (1) only 2048 iterations AND (2) not memory-hard.

Comment: `-iter` [was added](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/1fdde9170cbe36c9cd7bf9dc712836f591f7d511) to the pkcs12 command

Comment: @muxmuse: and that's not the only change; editted. Thanks for reminding me.